# Battery Problems

Tags: motorcycle, battery, voltage

I am on my second 12v motorcycle battery in a couple of weeks. Will a faulty regulator, ie too higher volts, cause this? Also I have upgraded my ct110 to a 160cc, without upgrading the stock reg. all works well for a few days, then gone.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Yes, a faulty regulator can cause it to overcharge. if you find the batteries were boiled over (liquid came out of the caps), it could definitely be overcharging. You can also put a multimeter on it to see if it's getting too much juice. Anything over ~14.5vdc would be too much.

Answer (score 0):

Your best friend with a questionable regulator or frequently failing batteries is a voltmeter.

Recently I had a battery go dead after a couple of days.  It turned out that it would charge OK, and the regulator worked OK, but the ignition switch was intermittent.  After several hours with the generator/alternator disconnected, the battery would be dead.

See if you can get a voltmeter, to carry with you, and frequently monitor what is happening.  Then post your findings.  You will get much better help.

But to answer your question, yes a disfunctional (over voltage) regulator could cause your symptoms.  A low cost voltmeter will be less than your next battery.